# How to show / hide scheduled notification based on condition?

Tags: flutter, onesignal

How can I show / hide scheduled notification based on condition?

Example Use case -

Let's say To-Do tasks notifications are scheduled for 10 users at a specific time of 1:30 PM
and some users have already completed the task before 1:30 PM.

Now scheduled notification are sent at 1:30 PM
And I don't want to show notification to those users who have completed their task already ( before 1:30 PM )
and want to show only to those users who haven't completed the task yet.

currently oneSignal does not have any method handler to handle notification in background for flutter, having such method could have help running custom logic and deciding to show / hide the notification.

Comment: You can create task bool fields in local Storage. If task completed change to true. Before sending notification check local storage.

Comment: @SulaymonNe'matov Using scheduled notification so it will be sent on specific time